# ASP.NET-MVC How to serve static content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I mostly want to have a static website, but I made it and ASP.NET-MVC application to serve a simple http post request to save something in database. Sometimes in future perhaps there will be a View implemented but not at the moment.
What I found is some weird behavior that I cannot explain why?

Site structure is:

```
Root/
    index.html
    test.html
    img/
        image.png
        test.html
```

The server is IIS 8.9 hosted.

My route config and controller are:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "ApiPostData",
             url: "api/{action}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Api" }
        );
}

public class ApiController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostSomeData(SomeData someData)
    {
            // save to database
            return Json(true);
    }
}
```

But his behaves completely wrong and unpredictable:
In examples:

www.mysite.com -> displays index.html OK

www.mysite.com/index.html -> error 500

www.mysite.com/img/image.png -> image is shwon which is OK

www.mysite.com/img/test.html -> error 500

www.mysite.com/api/postsomedata -> invokes controller method as it should

This is completely illogical. Why does server makes distinction between static context.
I need an explanation of this behavior and a way to force IIS to serve static content.

Comment: What exactly is the 500 error you are getting?

Comment: 500 server error, that is all it says.

Comment: Also confusing is the fact that one static file is served, the other is not. I am lost without a clue.

Comment: That's really strange. Just checked in my project and `.html` files are served properly. Take a look [here](http://codingstill.com/2011/09/handling-server-errors-in-asp-net/) and the second part of the article where it mentions how to get more details on the 500 error. This might give you a clue

Comment: I have been tjrough all of that and much more. It is hard to make error pages in asp.net, but mvc is obviously screwed far more. All I could gather is that MVC application does not work with static content, ando docs on that.

Comment: @freedomn-m What routes? Can you please copy paste one. Shoul I add route?

Comment: I didn't suggest to make an error page, but enable the following in your web.config `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />` and `<asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>` to get more details for the 500 error.

Comment: @tasos Could you somehow make your web.config available. I would like to replicate your effort.